# In Clojure, how can I convert a long int to a rational?

Tags: clojure, rational-number

How can I convert a long int to a rational in Clojure?

That does not work:

```
user> (class (/ 5 1))
java.long.Long
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`rationalize`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rationalize). But that doesn't do what you want -- it still returns a long if the denominator is a 1. However, if you want this for type testing purposes, the Clojure function [`rational?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rational_q) returns true for longs.

If you really want Ratio types, I think you'll have to write it yourself, since the source of `rationalize` dives immediately into the underlying Java.

```
(clojure.lang.Ratio.
   (. BigInteger (valueOf 3))
   (. BigInteger (valueOf 1)))
; 3/1
```

Perhaps:

```
(defn myrationalize
   [num]
   (if (integer? num)
      (clojure.lang.Ratio.
         (. BigInteger (valueOf num))
         (. BigInteger (valueOf 1)))
      (rationalize num)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to *explicitly* convert a long into a rational.

Clojure will convert

- a rational (`clojure.lang.Ratio`) into a long (`java.lang.Long`) when it *can*: when the denominator is or can be made to be `1`;
- longs or other ints into a rational when it *must*:  when a division cannot be resolved to a denominator of `1`.

Thus

`(type (/ 4 2))
; java.lang.Long`

`(type (/ 4 3))
; clojure.lang.Ratio`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I know that. I don't need it but I want it, and the question is *how can I do it if I want*.